# What's the best way to declare a 2D vector in term of memory

Tags: c++, vector

I know 3 manners to declare a 2D vector of known size but I don't know which one is optimal for the management of memory.

I didn't find a pertinent answer so I came to you:

```
1)
 vector<vector<float> > a(1000,vector<float>(2000));

 for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<2000;j++)
    a[i][j]=i+j;

  //print the vector or something else

2)  vector<vector<float> > a(1000);
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        a[i]=vector<float>(2000);

    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<2000;j++)
          a[i][j]=i+j;

    //print the vector or something else


3) vector<vector<float> > a(1000); vector<float> b(2000);
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        a[i]=b;

   vector<float>().swap(b); //destroy the temporary vector b

   for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
       for(int j=0;j<2000;j++)
          a[i][j]=i+j;

     //print the vector or something else
```

Comment: Obviously is number 1, from every aspect (i.e., readability, performance, maintenance).

Comment: In the end the vector `a` will be just the same in all three cases.

Comment: If you have a known size, it is better to use an array.

Comment: @Striker means `std::array` :)

Comment: For what you posted, i'd rather use `std::vector<std::array<float,2000>> a(1000);`

Comment: thank for your reponses. @WhozCraig why you prefered to use vector and array in the same time ?

Comment: @Anass: a propose you a fourth variant: instead of `a[i]=vector<float>(2000);` (variant 2) or `a[i]=b;` (variant 3), you can resize the vector: `a[i].resize(2000);`. But I think as 101010: the best is the variant 1.

Comment: ok thank you @max66 ;)